# Default image not showing up when using each_with_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show a default image in case one of the photos is blank,  but Its not working. 
The image is not being painted into the HTML, so it's a rails issue.

My code is:

```
 <% photos = album.photos.limit(5) %>
    <% photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
      <% if index == 0 %>
        <img class="photo-album-element" src="<%= photo.photo_url(:big) %>" alt="">
      <% else %>
        <% if photo.present? %>
          <img class="photo-album-element" src="<%= photo.photo_url(:thumb) %>" alt="">
        <% elsif photo.blank? %>
          <%= image_tag "default_album.png" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The image is not being painted into the HTML"? Are all the photos not displaying? Or some photos not displaying? Or is there any error message? We will be more able to offer suggestions if there is more information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AdlerHsieh, I mean that the default image is not in the DOM, so it's a Rails issue, not a URL issue

Comment: Where is `default_album.png` currently stored?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have default_album.png in app/assets/images it should be showing.